# Fetch not working in React Native new architecture

Tags: react-native, fetch, react-native-hermes, react-native-fabric

Can't seem to get `fetch()` working in my React Native app (should work out of the box). Using the new architecture with RN `0.70.4`, TypeScript, and a setup to import ES modules.

Every time `fetch()` is called, this error is printed in the console:

```
'Tried to call timer with ID %s but no such timer exists.', 6
```

Using this test button:

```
      <Button
        title="Test"
        onPress={async () => {
          console.log('PRESSED');

          const promise = fetch('https://www.google.com');
          console.log('promise:', promise);

          try {
            const res = await promise;
            console.log('res:', res);
          } catch (err: unknown) {
            console.log('err:', err);
          }
        }}
      />
```

When pressed, only `PRESSED` appears in the console, with no other log messages. In the Flipper network panel, it looks like there is no network call made.

When I add `import fetch from 'cross-fetch';`, I get 2 lines of console output:

```
18:17:27.196  32561  appname  PRESSED
18:17:27.210  32561  appname  'promise:', { _h: 0, _i: 0, _j: null, _k: null }
```

but nothing after that; weirdly, though, the successful network call appears in the flipper network logs.

Any idea what's going on here?!

Comment: i'm using react native's `fetch`, it run normally with your test. I use `"react": "18.1.0", "react-native": "0.70.4"`

Answer (score 0):

You should use async/await with fetch. You are seeing `{ _h: 0, _i: 0, _j: null, _k: null }` because network call takes some time to execute and you are not using async/await so the response is an unresolved promise.
You can also use `.then` and `.catch`

Comment: There is an `await` statement below...why does the promise not resolve or reject when it is awaited there?

Comment: Why are you fetching google.com? I don't think it will return anything.

Comment: It's just for an example to demonstrate why the fetch is not working! Try fetching it; you get an HTML document back typically.

Comment: I added await before fetch keyword. It did return response but not HTML doc. If it's not working you can use apisause or axios. Both are great. 
I am suspecting the issue is related with fetch. You can try this example on official doc. https://reactnative.dev/docs/network